# Get all flash data from session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am saving a cache of Laravel responses and its working fine. I am using a middleware that checks if there exists a cache for the request and return the cached response instead of generating that response again.

But there is a problem with flash messages when there is a flash message to be shown to the user it returns the cached response which doesn't have any flash message.

Therefore I want to check if there is a flash message without knowing the key. So that I can return the non-cached response with a flash message.

Here is that middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ttl=1440)
    {
        if(authenticate_user() != null || $request->isMethod('post'))
            return $next($request);
        $params = $request->query(); unset($params['_method']); ksort($params);
        $key = md5(url()->current().'?'.http_build_query($params));
        if($request->get('_method')=='purge')
            Cache::forget($key);
        if(Cache::has($key)){
            $cache = Cache::get($key);
            $response = response($cache['content']);
            $response->header('X-Proxy-Cache', 'HIT');
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
            Cache::put($key,['content' => $response->content(), 'headers' => array_map(function($element){ return implode(',', $element); }, $response->headers->all())],$ttl);
            $response->header('X-Proxy-Cache', 'MISS');
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Here is the `dd(session())`. In case it can help someone

[image: Screenshot]

I want the data corresponding to the `success` key.

But, I don't want to use a specific key to get flash data.
I just want to check if there is a flash message irrespective of the key used to store that data.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel internally keeps track of flash data using `_flash` variable you may try this

```
    if(  Cache::has($key)  &&  empty(session('_flash')['new'])  ){
        $cache = Cache::get($key);
        $response = response($cache['content']);
        $response->header('X-Proxy-Cache', 'HIT');
    }
    else {
        $response = $next($request);
        Cache::put($key,['content' => $response->content(), 'headers' => array_map(function($element){ return implode(',', $element); }, $response->headers->all())],$ttl);
        $response->header('X-Proxy-Cache', 'MISS');
    }
```

For some extra info incase you might need to tweak a little : If you get session in an array say `$session` then `$session['flash']['new']` refers to the data that has been just now flashed.So if you have just flashed "*we have just sent you and email with the instructions to reset your password.*" in your action then the message will be under `$session['flash']['new']` in your session array; upon second refresh it will be transferred to `$session['flash']['old']` and `$session['flash']['new']` will now be empty (unless you reflash) on 3rd refresh it will be nowhere.

So in essence it will prevent cache if you have flashed something for the current request.